# How to change the value of TextField with RawKeyboardListener in flutter(framework version 3.10)?

Tags: flutter, dart, frameworks, textfield

I'm writing an app with flutter in windows platform.
I have a problem when I want to change the value of TextField with arrow key up/down.

I used RawKeyboardListener, and set `_controller.text`(TextEditingController) as what I want, like below:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TextField Arrow Keys Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TextField Arrow Keys Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyHomePage();
}

class _MyHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  List menuList = ['apple', 'banana', 'cat'];
  int menuIdx = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 150,
          child: RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: FocusNode(),
            onKey: (event) {
              if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
                if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp ||
                    event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
                    menuIdx = max(menuIdx - 1, 0);
                  }
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                    menuIdx = min(menuIdx + 1, menuList.length - 1);
                  }
                  
                  _controller.text = menuList[menuIdx];
                }
              }
            },
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button 1'),
          focusNode: FocusNode(
            onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Button 2'),
          focusNode: FocusNode(
            onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Originally,it worked in old version of flutter framework. However, after I update the flutter framework to newest version(3.10), the app will crash at:

```
_controller.text = menuList[menuIdx];
```

Therefore, I add `setState()`, but it still crash.

```
setState(() {
  _controller.text = menuList[menuIdx];
});
```

Do you have any idea to deal with this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add your error to the question.

Comment: It just crash withou any error message...